# Open Server: работа PostgreSQL в php7

Tags: php, postgresql, openserver

Здравствуйте.
Использую:
**Open Server x64 5.2.2**
**Apache-PHP-7-x64+Nginx-1.10**
**PHP-7.1-x64**
**PostgreSQL-9.6-x64**

И это все дело не работает... Выдает это сообщение, когда пытаюсь зайти в phpPgAdmin:

> **Deprecated**: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; Misc has a deprecated
>   constructor in
>   **C:\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\classes\Misc.php**
>   on line **8**
>
> **Warning**: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already
>   sent by (output started at
>   C:\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\classes\Misc.php:8)
>   in
>   **C:\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\lib.inc.php**
>   on line **56**
>
> **Warning**: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers
>   already sent (output started at
>   C:\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\classes\Misc.php:8)
>   in
>   **C:\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\libraries\lib.inc.php**
>   on line **56**
>
> **Warning**: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   C:\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\classes\Misc.php:8)
>   in
>   **C:\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\classes\Misc.php**
>   on line **526**

Как быть и что делать? Спасибо.

Comment: https://ospanel.io/forum/

Comment: отключите показ ошибок, либо исправьте misc.php, либо обновите phpPgAdmin до версии совместимой с с пхп 7.1

Comment: Версия phpPgAdmin? И попробуйте версию php снизить, написано же что такой конструктор не поддерживается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работе `PHP` с `PostgreSQL` ничего не мешает хоть отдельно хоть вместе и ничего заметным образом в этом плане не менялось уже много лет.

> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; Misc has a deprecated constructor in C:\OSPanel\modules\system\html\openserver\phppgadmin\classes\Misc.php on line 8

Это предупреждение уровня `E_DEPRECATED` не имеет ровным счётом никакого отношения к базам данных, а лишь к самому PHP. [Говорит о том](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.deprecated.php), что конструкторы объектов в стиле `PHP4` с именем метода идентичным имени класса официально объявлены устаревшими и разработчики должны заменить конструктор на специальное имя `__construct` появившееся в PHP 5.0.

Остальные варнинги всего лишь спровоцированы первым варнингом и сами по себе здесь роли не играют.

Вам необходимо обновить это приложение, либо использовать более старую версию PHP (не выше 5.6). Отключать предупреждения `E_DEPRECATED` настоятельно не рекомендую т.к. вы очевидно что-то разрабатываете и для этого настраиваете локальный веб-сервер.

Comment: а что если заняться правками правками того файла? это будет трудно, а по времени?

Comment: Для этого варнинга исправление элементарное. Но ваша версия приложения очевидно не тестировалось на версиях PHP как минимум старше 5.6, так что возможен букет других ошибок связанных с неподдерживаемой приложением версией языка выполнения.

Comment: Большое спасибо)
А есть ли в сети нормальные (доверенные) версии phpPgAdmin для PHP выше седьмой версии?

Comment: Посмотрите на сайте phppgadmin changelog'и, с какого релиза добавили поддержку каких версий PHP. Я пользуюсь только `psql` клиентом.

Answer (score -1):

phpPgAdmin ? На LM 18.3 (Sylvia) достаточно консоли, в частности для работы с Drupal. А какую роль может играть phpPgAdmin ? Удобно просматривать. Но я не заметил, чтобы там работал например Alter...

Comment: Извините, не совсем понятно, а как ваше сообщение отвечает на вопрос заданный в этом топике?